# How to compile sources into rpmbuild BUILDROOT?

Tags: linux, redhat, centos6, rpm

All the information I can find about building RPMs seems to pre-date CentOS 6, and as a complete package-building novice running CentOS 6.5, I'm rather stuck.

All the tutorials I've read mention one `BUILD` directory and state that during the `%install`  the files are copied from from their native location (`/usr/bin/whatever`) and packaged up.

However, in the CentOS 6.5 image I'm building on, a new `BUILDROOT` directory appears which I **think** is designed to avoid you having to install the binaries at their native locations, and hence also avoid the use of `sudo` with `make install`.

However, it seems this isn't optional. When trying to package various sources written by other people `rpmbuild` completes the `make install` **successfully**, but then dies when it doesn't find the binaries under the `BUILDROOT`, because they weren't installed there.

After some digging, it seems that some Makefiles can take a `DESTDIR` argument, but only if the author supported it, and if they haven't I'm stuck. I've also read it's a bad idea to use `--prefix`

So, my question is:

How can I build and install **any** third-party sources into the BUILDROOT location?
Is there something rpmbuild can do for me that doesn't requiring patching someone else's code I don't understand?

Comment: You use whatever method was provided by the developer. If they didn't provide any method, you yell very loudly at them. The thing you do _not_ do is to install to your system as you will contaminate the build server, and quite likely the package.

Comment: Understood. I've altered my question slightly

Answer (score 1):

> How can I build and install **any** third-party sources into the BUILDROOT location? Is there something rpmbuild can do for me [...]?

Not really. `rpmbuild` is a essentially a wrapper, and does rely on instructions provided by  the Makefile, etc. The onus is on the developer(s) of the source, not on `rpmbuild`.